# Extracting unnamed(?) elements from a list in R

Tags: r

```
Browse[1]> lmc
[[1]]

t test of coefficients:

                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)       0.0090841  0.0063588  1.4286 0.154840
m[, "FX_RET_28"]  0.1122490  0.1599463  0.7018 0.483705
m[, "FX_RET_42"]  0.1702606  0.1041854  1.6342 0.103944
m[, "FX_RET_51"] -0.4735956  0.2450406 -1.9327 0.054823 .
m[, "FX_RET_52"]  0.2475292  0.1458240  1.6975 0.091321 .
m[, "FX_RET_53"] -0.5569527  0.1945823 -2.8623 0.004699 **
m[, "FX_RET_60"] -0.3191905  0.2887157 -1.1056 0.270379
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Browse[1]> str(lmc)
List of 1
 $ : coeftest [1:7, 1:4] 0.00908 0.11225 0.17026 -0.4736 0.24753 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:7] "(Intercept)" "m[, \"FX_RET_28\"]" "m[, \"FX_RET_42\"]" "m[, \"FX_RET_51\"]" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Estimate" "Std. Error" "t value" "Pr(>|t|)"
  ..- attr(*, "method")= chr "t test of coefficients"
```

I want to pull out the `Estimate` column into a vector with `(Intercept)`, `m[, "FX_RE_28"]`, etc. as the names of the elements. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: difficult without the object to check, but looks like it would be `lmc[[1]]$coeftest[,1]`

Comment: Browse[1]> lmc[[1]]$coeftest[,1]
Error in lmc[[1]]$coeftest : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: It is there in my original post.

Comment: It is the list returned from a coeftest call: lmc <- coeftest(x, vcov=NeweyWest(x, lag=w, prewhite=FALSE))

Comment: Sorry, I meant `dput(lmc)`

Comment: But maybe `lmc[[1]][,"Estimate"]`

Comment: sorry - what I meant is, could you print `class(lmc[[1])`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico, am a little challenged by the comment system. dput output seems to be too long. How can I paste it here?

Comment: Please add it to your question.

Comment: Michael's should work - coeftest is the class of `lmc[[1]]`

Comment: class(lmc[[1]])
[1] "coeftest"

Comment: does `lmc[[1]][,"Estimate"]` or `lmc[[1]][,1]` not work?  if not, which coeftest function is this? the one from the `sandwich` package?

Comment: sorry - lmtest not sandwich?

Comment: @MichaelChirico, lmc[[1]][,"Estimate"] works. I am not being able to mark it as the answer. Don't know why. Thanks to you and RichAtMango for your help.

Comment: i did nothing - was just buying @MichaelChirico some time ;)

Answer (score 1):

From the `str` output, one would predict that the values for the Estimate-column could be extracted with one of four incantations:

```
 lmc[[1]][ , 1]   # using just numerical indexing ... OR
 # Apparently not this: lmc[['coeftest']][ , "Estimate" ]  # Using character/name indexing
```

From the comments it appears that there was no name of the list element. Appears the "coeftest" is not a name but rather the class-type of the first (and only=) item in that list.

I thought (but was wrong) : The reason that `lmc[[1]]$coeftest[,1]` offered by RichAtMango fails is that the object is a list and `lmc[[1]]` delivers the first and only item of the list which is a matrix. This would have worked: `lmc[1]$coeftest[,1]` , because the `[.]`-function delivers a sublist (rather than the value itself) and it still would have had an element named 'coeftest'.

If you had wanted a one column matrix (which would display with the rownames on the side) then the call would have been:

```
lmc[['coeftest']][ , "Estimate" , drop=FALSE] # to avoid returning as a vector
```

You cannot "accept" comments as answers in SO. It's not clear why MichaelChirico didn't post an answer. He may have been too busy to post something he thought was sufficiently developed or maybe he wanted to to post `dput(lmc)` so he could offer a tested answer. I thought the downvote you got was unfair, since you did provide enough information to answer and the indexing difference between "[" and "[[" can be difficult to get for persons beginning with R. Your request needed understanding of both the indexing of lists and the indexing of R matrices.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful feedback. I get the results back using the numerical indexing, lmc[[1]][ , 1]. However, lmc[['coeftest']][[, "Estimate"] returns null. In fact, lmc[['coeftest']] returns null. That is what led me to think of it as an unnamed element. In my limited understanding, given a simple list like below works the way I would expect but that does not seem to work with coeftest. `abc <- list(e1 = c(1,2,3), e2 = c("hello", "goodbye")); abc[["e1"]]` produces `[1] 1 2 3`